# modrewrite not working on wamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

mod rewrite is not working with wampserver. My .htacess file is as follow

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

when I remove  and  from starting an ending it says internal server error but when I keep them it doesn't effects any thing asif it doesn't got into the  tag what I

Want to do is redirect the URL from a folder Say MVC to a sub folder say MVC/public

Comment: Although I get internal server error when I write some garbage text in .htacess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MVC/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /public/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi but this is also not working infact it seems like htacess is not effecting but when working with wordpress its htacess always works and I have also checked that allowOverride is set to All so that is also not an issue

Comment: You didn't tell anything about Wordpress in your question. Provide all the details. In which directory you have wordpress installed? What is location of above .htaccess etc

Comment: Sorry for misleading comment I have  mentioned WordPress as an example

Comment: But you removed all references to original problem of MVC and public etc. This looks like a totally different question.

Comment: Ya it is. What I figured out is that it is all because of wamp server not supporting .htacess file

Comment: How do you know wamp doesn't support `.htaccess`? I use it all the time.

Comment: because anything accept garbage characters doesn't give any  error for ex if I write "asdfgh" it will show internal server error but if i write any valid syntax in .htacess it is not getting affected

Comment: Does your httpd.conf looks similar to what I pasted above??

Comment: If garbage characters are spring 500 error then at least htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Then why .htaccess have no effect when every thing is written correctly

Comment: In fact it displays directory listing of my file

Comment: Add `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` to make it show index.php OR index.html

Comment: I meant that if .htaccess was working then directory listing wont have displayed

Comment: Directory listing may OR may not be related to .htaccess working

Comment: Resolved my error it was all because mode rewrite was not enabled in my http.conf Thanks